# cart.discount.enabled returns "true" in advanced demo, "false" on published page.

Tags: bigcartel

I am wondering why cart.discount.enabled returns different values. I get it as "true" when I'm using the advanced editor on my admin page, but when I save and view the actual page (both in and out of maintenance mode) I get a "false" response. Why is this?

I have discounts set up and active right now. Any idea why this is coming back false?

I hope there's not some easy thing like a "turn on discounts" checkbox, I've combed through all the settings and not seen one. '

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have seamless checkout with Stripe set as your store's Checkout option - which moves all of the shipping and discount calculations to the separate Checkout page.

Unfortunately the design editor hasn't been updated to reflect these new changes with the seamless checkout, so those variables will still return "true" (as if you're using PayPal's checkout) when previewing your store.

Comment: I am using Stripe for checkout, which is really nice. I'd say it's worth having the discount code on the next page to avoid a paypal interface. I might just write a quick line on the cart page like "Have a discount code? Enter it on the checkout page!" and that's that. Thanks so much I wouldn't have thought of that as a factor!